# Clear header and White background for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have been looking all over the web for this issue, but I have not been able to find anything helpful. Any help or direction will be highly appreciated.

I have a UICollectionView with a header (that contains simple text/title) and then a grid. What I want is to have the header background as clear and rest of the area below header should have white background.

Cell background will not work because the actual space that is required to be white is the visible area on top, left, bottom and right of the cells.

Thanking in advance for your help.

**EDIT:** You can think of it as a UICollectionView is added as a subview to another UIView. The headerView (UICollectionReusableView) should have clear background so that we can see the parent UIView. where as the rest of the collectionView (Cell area and space around them) should have white background. It will look like as if the title is floating.

[image]

Comment: if you upload image it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

for me I used UICollectionReusableView for my HeaderView of my UICollectionViewController. Setting the background color with

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

did the trick.